# High usage of Intel CPU! [18.04 LTS]

Tags: gnome, intel, cpu, 18.04, budgie

Please, help! My Ubuntu is using so much CPU, since 16.04 LTS!
I always solve it closing my laptop and opening again, but this is not cool to do every day.

(this links is for screenshots)

Nothing is using ALL THIS GRRRRRR:

[image: Nothing is using ALL THIS GRRRRRR]

High usage of CPU!!!:

[image: High usage of CPU!!!]

**My CPU:** Intel® Core™ i3-3217U CPU @ 1.80GHz × 4
**My RAM:** 4 GB DDR3
**My OS:** Ubuntu 18.04 LTS - Budgie Desktop (but this problem has happened with previous Ubuntu "pure flavor")

[SORRY FOR BAD ENGLISH]

Comment: open up a terminal by issuing  `ctrl+alt+t`   then type in  `top` hit enter what appears at top of listing is probably offending process ... if its a browser then kill off your browser tabs some web pages hog CPU

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the process that hogs the CPU is not a program you are running but a system process.

To see other processes in the System Monitor go to the menu (vertical 3 lines at the top) and select the option "All Processes" instead of the the default "My Processes"

If you like to see these in text (which will also be more convenient to cut and paste in questions) you can use the `ps` command to list processes:

Open a terminal (`ctrl+alt+t`) 
write `ps -el' to get a list of running processes
write`top` to monitor processes and cpu

Using this will help to identify the process that uses resources and look for a more specific solution.